# Narrow down the type from a given key

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a React Hook using TS. As arguments, I am giving the key and the value that will be assigned to this key. I would like the type of the value to be restricted by reading the given key.

```
export function useFormFields<T, K extends keyof T>(initialValues: T) {
  const [formFields, setFormFields] = useState<T>(initialValues)
  const createChangeHandler = (key: K, value: T[K]) => {
    setFormFields((prev: T) => ({ ...prev, [key]: value }))
  }

  return { formFields, createChangeHandler }
}
```

When I use the **createChangeHandler** function, the key part works, but it combines the types for the value.

Let's say I have an object / interface like the following :

```
interface User {
  name: string,
  age: number
}
```

I would like the crateChangeHandler to throw an error on the next example

```
createChangeHandler('name', 1)
//Works because the combined type are "string" | "number"
//I'd like to have "string" only
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you've got the *wrong scope* for the `K` generic type parameter.  When a generic function is called, all its type parameters will be specified right there and then; it is not possible to *defer* specifying a type parameter until some later time.  When you call `useFormFields` you know what `T` is but not what `K` will be.  But with your version of the function, `K` will be inferred anyway.  And since there's nothing there to help the compiler infer, it will be widened to its [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints), which is `keyof T`.

Instead you want `createChangeHandler()` itself to be generic in `K`, and so the type parameter for `K` should be moved to its scope:

```
function useFormFields<T>(initialValues: T) {
  const [formFields, setFormFields] = useState<T>(initialValues)
  const createChangeHandler = <K extends keyof T>(key: K, value: T[K]) => {
    setFormFields((prev: T) => ({ ...prev, [key]: value }))
  }

  return { formFields, createChangeHandler }
}
```

This gives the behavior you want:

```
createChangeHandler("age", 10); // okay
createChangeHandler('name', 1); // error!
// Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMDKMCGN1wC+cAZlBCHAORTo4DGMVA3AFCsnIB2jwEXKDADFoIIcHQAbACaoAPABUAfAApgXYDGA5JANR3J0qAFxwFASkSs4cev1TwA2iVHipsgDRwMMEVDESMqgAunAAvIJYuPiKquqa2noGRubWtvbw9LR46ADCABY4XADm6AASRdKS6FDhcHIA0nDoAB74XLJwANboAJ4QJGaqPb2mDV4AbsmmCo4NwZZhSlY2Nj5+Ae6oKipgtBMzi8sqSAB053voE16OI8GmU5KGROapNoTsNrQwyFACSC5-G4gl4snR8AUiqUKh1qrUPh9WOp8FASAwCABVDC1BBpLg4EDoUwOKDqYoeNI4UqmLjIEAAIxqrERdi4DhQpixNTqSHxhNMACIhLRpAKvFSiXAAMwAViIbFYrPZANcgU8tmyEMKJXKlThRDqaHQG2BshUyHMCrBOUhOphVRqKgFErFcAAjAAGS2KzV5bXQvWOqh89BULxuy1wAD0UeaUHIUAAhKwY3AAIJQYp09BceADOAwXpgAjBumMqBUODAVBwLgQeA4VCoYDFfH06oFiBwMA4KAE9AouD5wvF6gkslUVhAA)

Comment: Thanks a bunch ! I am relatively new to TS and Hooks. I was so close, yet so far

Answer (score 1):

Your function `useFormFields` is generic, but the `createChangeHandler` function that is returned from it isn't. By the time you invoke `useFormFields`, from the compiler's viewpoint you've fixed those types to be a union. This is what the compiler sees:

```js
const handler: (key: keyof User, value: User[keyof User]) => void = 
  useFormFields(someUser).createChangeHandler
```

You need to move the generic onto the returned function in order for the type to be narrowed at the call site of the handler:

```js
export function useFormFields<T>(initialValues: T) {
  const [formFields, setFormFields] = useState<T>(initialValues)
  const createChangeHandler = <K extends keyof T>(key: K, value: T[K]) => {
    setFormFields((prev: T) => ({ ...prev, [key]: value }))
  }

  return { formFields, createChangeHandler }
}
```

now the compiler sees:

```js
const handler: <K extends keyof User>(key: K, value: User[K]) => void = 
  useFormFields(someUser).createChangeHandler;
```

And it will be able to narrow the value type as you change the key input.

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVyQZ2ADFoBbIzYAGwBN8AeAFQD4AKAfUxUywEMqAavyTB8ALjiMAlHADeAKDhwowGEii56AaTigYwFHTgBrYAE8ICSW3amzErQBo47AG7DgExgG0tAXRkAXmY5RSU4AHoIvG5SMCpgUgN9GjCAX3kM+S59KAReNGA4AFVCKFClFF4kiXwYKC4AcwBuMN5GzzgUJFIAI2AoVqy0HDq8MolSgbhAiq7qzoAiAHVMAHc1zCpFxzaOiQBGTPkRlDGAC15DBPLZgmIyCmo6VnuoKXl5S+uB1kX24A7OAHKStb40G5-KpJIEg5pAA)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I selected the first one as solution because he answered first. But yours is as good.

Comment: @Wiwwil if you are accepting answers based on which one was posted first then you should accept this one; I’m pretty sure that it came in a few minutes before mine.

Comment: If I order by oldest, it's yours coming first. If I could choose both as good answer I would. They're both fantastic and complete. I upvoted both. Maybe upvote his ? I can't do much, but if you want him to have the selected answer let me know

Comment: Since you've already accepted an answer, the accepted answer is always pinned to the top, regardless of sort order. For future reference, if you hover over the "yesterday" in "answered yesterday", you can see the timestamp for any answer. As long as the accepted answer correctly answers your question, that's all that matters.