# How the Pick<T, K> utility type work in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I wrote a function in Typescript to pick some selected properties from an object. After some tries I got the type annotation working correctly but I'm having a hard time to grasp how it's working!

Here is the function below or see it in the [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMATnAtgHgCoE8AOApooQB5SFgAmAzonAEYBWh0AfABQBQi9zrUAFyI8RLgEphAb0T4YEANbDMAaUK4S5SrUQL1cYCIKFOAOnN7cNYWtwBtALrjEAXjaIACvIU5jAGkRbdwBfRCkeRBRCKBAUJHDeXjlFVXVNCmo6SwMjIjMLdWtA9UdJT29fIgCgsIjExAgEGihIwhoQABshTwBDFFgejswvFNFCavU2dxcw4IBuOsTgOBREDkawZt00nMsaZyj2rrtLB1c%20FmgT9QcF%20t4omLjWo5aeuhGfMYncNjvE4J%20CLzLjBLhcDZbIgoGgIc4JRBgHroQjCABEAEEOmQ0UDeD0AOaoxAAZgALHjEDAaABlGJUSjdKAoEDjCI9KhUQ5FBG8CAwKC4dEAJR61AwAH0AMIC3C4xbNHoUEViqiSulKwjy3iA0ELCFNFrAGBdQhRKjnVAYDjQ2FgcSmZIKDhopEo3GINGErXiBaQuDY0wdOAEjjG03m31AA).

```
function from<Type extends object>(
  object: Type
): { pick: <Key extends keyof Type>(...keys: Key[]) => Pick<Type, Key> } {
  return {
    pick<Key extends keyof Type>(...keys: Key[]): Pick<Type, Key> {
      const result: Partial<Pick<Type, Key>> = {};
      for (const key of keys) result[key] = object[key];
      return result as Pick<Type, Key>;
    },
  };
}

const person = {
  name: "Alex",
  age: 34,
  isStudent: true,
  address: {
    city: "Random_City",
    state: "Random_State",
  },
};

const filtered = from(person).pick("name", "age");
console.log(filtered);
```

Here the type of `filtered` object is of type `Pick<typeof person, "name" | "age">`

And the type of `from` function is:

```
type from = <Type extends object>(object: Type) => {
 pick: <Key extends keyof Type>(...keys: Key[]) => Pick<Type, Key> 
};
```

The `from` function takes an object and returns another object that contains a method called `pick`. The `pick` method takes a rest argument of type `(keyof Type)[]` and returns object of type `Pick<Type, Key>`.

Now from the docs, I learned that `Keys` argument of the `Pick<Type, Keys>` utility type can only be a **string literal or union of string literals**.

But the returned `pick` function takes an (rest) array of keys so it's type is `(keyof Type)[]` and it's neither a string literal nor an union of string literals! **How it's working then?** Or am I making any mistakes?

Thanks in advance <3. I highly appreciate your time on SO.

Comment: Your example code has four instances of `Pick<Type, Key>` and in all four cases `Key` is a type parameter constrained to `keyof Type`, so it is definitely a keylike type (it does not have to be a "string literal or union of string literals", but it does have to be some type that is known to be assignable to `string | number | symbol`).  You seem to be confusing the type of the function parameter and the type parameter; the fact that a value of type `Key[]` exists doesn't mean that `Key` is an array type any more than having a bottle of milk means that the milk itself must be a bottle.

Comment: Or, conversely, if `Key[]` is an arraylike type, you'd have a problem writing `Pick<Type, Key[]>`.  But you're not writing `Pick<Type, Key[]>`; you're writing `Pick<Type, Key>`, so the issue is whether `Key` is keylike, not if `Key[]` is keylike.

Comment: Does this make sense?  I can't tell if this confusion is the sort of thing that makes for a good question/answer pair, so I'm not sure if I'm up to answering it.

Comment: @jcalz thanks for you explanation. Could you kindly explain why the second version (see the update) is not working?

Comment: I'm looking at the playground link from your edit and nothing is obviously "not working"; am I supposed to be seeing an error or something?  Please review the guidelines for what constitutes a [mre]; the particular problem needs more description than "it doesn't work" in order to be conveyed to your audience.

Comment: @jcalz I've updated my question (see the end of the question please). The thing that's not working is the __type__ of the returned object from `from(obj).pick(...)` function call.

Comment: Oh, so it's essentially the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66571059/2887218) and its answer.  When you call `from(obj)`, the type parameters `Type` and `Key` must be specified then and there; you can't "defer" the specification until some later call.  And `Type` can be inferred from `obj`, but `Key` cannot be inferred from anything and it falls back to its constraint.  If you want the result of `from(obj)` to be generic in `Key`, then you need to move `Key` to that scope, as in your first example.

Comment: Has this explained things enough for you? Note that the question before and after the update seem to be completely different; if you are no longer asking about whether `Key` is an array or not, then you should probably remove all of that from the question entirely.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks a lot for the explanation and reference to that other question you answered. Now I understand why the second example was not working and for the first one I guess I've to acknowledge that's how typescript work. Again thanks for giving me your precious time <3

Comment: So what do you want to see with this question? Do you understand the issue in the original and now current version of the question? Or has it not been explained to your satisfaction?

Comment: @jcalz I don't know. Should I delete it? As you explained before, __(it does not have to be a "string literal or union of string literals", but it does have to be some type that is known to be assignable to string | number | symbol)__ and if that's how it works then I don't have anymore more questions.